# adding two nodes and deleting one while comparing it

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

In a linked list I want to compare each node to the other one and if they are like terms then add them together. I have a problem going through the linked list and then adding together.

my main.cpp:

```
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include "list.h"
  int main(){
  Poly poly=new_list();
  Poly poly2=new_list();
  Poly merged= new_list();
  int n;
  int deg;
  float coef;
  n=1;
  while (n==1)
     {
      cout<<"Enter coefficient ";
      cin>> coef;
      cout<<"Enter degree ";
      cin>>deg;
      insert_front(&poly,coef,deg);
      cout<<"Enter 1 to continue or 0 to break ";
      cin>>n;
  }
  print_list(poly);
  cout<<"sorted\n";
  reduce(poly);

}
```

this is my header file:

```
//list.h                                                                       
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
struct Term {
    int deg;
    float coef;
    Term *next;
};
typedef Term* Poly;
Poly new_list();
void insert_front(Poly* ppoly,int deg, float coef);
void print_list(Poly poly);
void delete_front(Poly* ppoly);
bool is_empty(Poly poly);
Poly merge(Poly *ppoly,Poly *ppoly2);
void split_list(Poly* ppoly,Poly *ppoly2);
void mergesort(Poly* pl);
void reduce(Poly poly);
#endif
```

and I have all the functions that put users coefficients and degrees of the polynomial and print them out, also mergesort them from lowest to highest degree.

functions:

list.cpp
    #include "list.h"
    Poly new_list(){
        Poly poly = 0;
        return poly;
    }
    void insert_front(Poly* ppoly,int deg, float coef){
        Term* t;
        t = new Term;
        t->coef=coef;
        t->deg = deg;
        t->next = *ppoly;
        *ppoly = t;
        return;
    }
    void print_list(Poly poly){
        Term* p;
        p = poly;
        if(p == 0)
            cout << "--- empty list ---";
        while(p !=0){
          cout << p->deg<<"x^"<coef<<" + ";
            p = p->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void delete_front(Poly* ppoly){
      Term* t;
      if( !is_empty(*ppoly) ){   // list is not empty
          t = (*ppoly);
          *ppoly = (*ppoly)->next;
          delete t;
      }
    }

```
bool is_empty(Poly poly){
  return (poly == 0); //return true if list empty                                                                                                                                                                                 
}

Poly merge(Poly* ppoly, Poly* ppoly2){
    Term **pp;
    Poly merged, list1,list2;
    merged= new_list();
    list1 = *ppoly;
    list2 = *ppoly2;
    pp= &merged;
    while(list1 != NULL && list2 != NULL){
        if(list2->coef > list1->coef){
           *pp = list1;
           list1 = list1->next;
           (*pp)->next = NULL;
        }else{
           *pp = list2;
           list2 = list2->next;
           (*pp)->next = NULL;
        }
        pp = &( (*pp)->next );
    }
    if(list1 != NULL)
        *pp = list1;
    if(list2 != NULL)
        *pp = list2;

    *ppoly = NULL;
    *ppoly2 = NULL;
    return merged;
}
void split_list(Poly* ppoly, Poly* ppoly2){
    Poly l1= *ppoly;
    Poly l2= *ppoly;
    Poly* pp = &l1;
    while( l2 != NULL){
        l2 = l2->next;
        if(l2 != NULL){
            l2 = l2->next;
            pp = &((*pp)->next);
        }
    }
    l2 = *pp;
    (*pp) = NULL;
    *ppoly=l1;
    *ppoly2=l2;
}
void mergesort(Poly* pl){
    Poly l1 = *pl;
    Poly l2 = new_list();
    Poly merged = new_list();
    if(l1 == NULL || l1->next == NULL)
        return; //sorted or empty                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    split_list(&l1,&l2);
    mergesort(&l1);
    mergesort(&l2);
    merged = merge(&l1,&l2);
    *pl = merged;
}
void reduce(Poly poly){
  mergesort(&poly);
  print_list(poly);
  int i=0;
  cout<<"combining like terms:"<<endl;
  Term* p;
  p=poly;
  if (p==0)
    cout<<"---empty list---";
  while(i=0){
    if (poly->coef==(poly->next)->coef){
      p->deg=(poly->deg)+((poly->next)->deg);
      poly=p;
      i=1;
    }
  }
  print_list(poly);
}
```

I have been doing this for couple of days and can't get this working. The problem is in the `reduce()` function.

For example if I have: `2x^2+2x^2+4x^2+3x^5`, it would print `8x^2+3x^5`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong here. Let's start with a simple case:

```
int main()
{
  Poly poly=new_list();

  insert_front(&poly,2,5);
  insert_front(&poly,2,5);

  reduce(poly);
  print_list(poly); // we hope for 4x^5

  return(0);
}
```

...but we get 2x^5. (Note that you should test a function in isolation if possible-- there's no need for interactivity or merging or all that other stuff.)

Now look at `reduce`:

```
void reduce(Poly poly){
  mergesort(&poly);
  print_list(poly);
  int i=0;
  cout<<"combining like terms:"<<endl;
  Term* p;
  p=poly;
  if (p==0)
    cout<<"---empty list---";
  while(i=0){
    if (poly->coef==(poly->next)->coef){
      p->deg=(poly->deg)+((poly->next)->deg);
      poly=p;
      i=1;
    }
  }
  print_list(poly);
}
```

You have "ceof" and "degree" the wrong way around, but that's just a problem of variable naming (albeit one that makes my eyes hurt).

You use `while(i=0)` where I think you meant `while(i==0)`. As written, it's an assignment which evaluates to `0`, so control never enters the loop. Suppose we fix that so that we do enter the loop:

```
int i=0;
Term* p;
p=poly;
while(i==0){
  if (poly->coef==(poly->next)->coef){
    p->deg=(poly->deg)+((poly->next)->deg);
    poly=p;
    i=1;
  }
}
```

If the first two terms don't match, `i` remains zero and we remain in the loop forever.
If the first two terms do match, `i=1` and we leave the loop, so no other terms will be considered.
Before leaving the loop we modify the first term-- and then set `poly=p`. But `poly` was already equal to `p`; this step does nothing, and the second term is still there.

I hope this is enough to get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: not really. Im still lost how we can make this loop go through all elements and if they are the same deg then they will add and other will stay the same. For example if I have 2x^2+2x^2 it will print 4x^2+ 2x^2 why it doesn't delete the 2x^2. and also if i have 2x^2+2x^2+1x^2 it will print 4x^2+2x^2+1x^2. It will not add the three things together

Comment: @CZ, build up from the simple to the complex: implement (and test) a `removeTerm` function. And you know how to write something that will iterate through a list-- look at `print_list`.

Comment: I know i should use 'while(p!=0)' but then it crashes

Comment: `print_list` doesn't crash. Get `removeTerm` working perfectly, then integrate it into `reduce`.

Comment: @CZ, read what I wrote: *implement (and test) a `removeTerm` function*, a function that removes a term from the list. To make it even simpler: it takes a single `Term*` as an argument, and removes the term *after* that one. Don't worry about iterating over the list until you're sure the that what you're doing to a single term is correct.

Comment: Node* t;
    if( poly!=0) ){  
        t = (*poly);
        *poly = (*poly)->next;
        delete t;

Comment: @CZ, why do you put code that doesn't compile into a comment? If and when you get stuck, edit your question.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, I'm giving up, i have been stack on this for like 30hrs or more now.